# How to copy a folder and all its subfolders and files into another folder

Tags: java

How can I copy a folder and all its subfolders and files into another folder?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apache Commons IO can do the trick for you. Have a look at [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

Comment: link is down. pls update

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29

Answer (score 53):

Choose what you like:

- FileUtils from Apache Commons IO (**the easiest and safest way**)

Example with FileUtils:

```
File srcDir = new File("C:/Demo/source");
File destDir = new File("C:/Demo/target");
FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

- Manually, [example before Java 7](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) (CHANGE: close streams in the finally-block)
- Manually, Java >=7

Example with AutoCloseable feature in Java 7:

```
public void copy(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation) throws IOException {
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        copyDirectory(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
    } else {
        copyFile(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
    }
}

private void copyDirectory(File source, File target) throws IOException {
    if (!target.exists()) {
        target.mkdir();
    }

    for (String f : source.list()) {
        copy(new File(source, f), new File(target, f));
    }
}

private void copyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException {        
    try (
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)
    ) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working but if an exception happens you won't close the streams : you should add a try catch finally block.

Comment: @Tim, that's true. Fixed

Comment: The `copyFile` can be enhanced by using the `Files#copy` method (as it uses native hooks if available).

Comment: There is an error. It is not working if I want to copy 1 file - because targeLocation should always be a folder, whereas in your code, it is always used as a file in copyFile.

Answer (score 2):

look at java.io.File for a bunch of functions.

you will iterate through the existing structure and mkdir, save etc to achieve deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA NIO will help to you to solve your problem. Please have a look on this
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/files.html#overwriting-existing-files.