# Calling static directory-copying method in Java

Tags: java, static, directory, ioexception

I try to use example from this question : [How to copy a folder and all its subfolders and files into another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368724/how-to-copy-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders-and-files-into-another-folder)

I made him static, and when I call copyDirectory(), I have an exception during program runs :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type IOException
```

At every line that uses this method.

I added

```
  throws IOException
```

for every method that uses copyDirectory()

Error's count had been shorted, but they remained at native java classes. And I can't edit them : it would be an infinite editing recursion :))

Advance I'm sorry for bad english.

UPD: (Using ApacheCommonsIO)

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
// the rest import
public class MyClass{
  public myMethod(){
   String src = "/home/user/dir_src";
   String dst = "/home/user/dir_dst";
   FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(src), new File(dst)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: its a compile time error,so first try to resolve compile time errors then go for exceptions

Comment: Yes, I use vim + eclim plugin.
I haven't "red lines" and compilation problems.

Comment: have you resolved complie time errors?

Comment: I resolved them by adding "throws IOException" at every method, that use copyDirectory(). 
Is wrong way, but haven't any idea how to fix them correct.

Comment: can you post your code? you have to handle the exceptions thrown somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Things here

1. You should format your method copyDirectory somehow like this, so it won't throw you all these exceptions:

```
    public static boolean copyDirectory(File source, File destination) {
      try{
        // Copy Stuff
        return true;
      catch(IOException e){
        // Your way of ErrorLogging
        return false;
      }
    }
```

1. For all the IO-Stuff like copying deleting and so on I would recommend you using ApachCommonIO: http://commons.apache.org/io/.

Edit:

Please try this code now, this should at least compile and give you a hint what is wrong:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
// the rest import
public class MyClass{
  public myMethod(){
   String src = "/home/user/dir_src";
   String dst = "/home/user/dir_dst";
   try{
      FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(src), new File(dst)); 
   catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrac();
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: As you recommended, I installed ApachCommonIO.
And I have the same problem :
 my line FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(src), new File(dst));
is highlighted with "Unhandled IO exception".

Comment: Please provide the code you are using. Maybe we will find a fault here. To ApacheCommonsIO, this is a library that provides methods that will handle CommonIO tasks like copy, delete and so on. Please check the Documentation for further information on how to you it.