# Android - copy files between internal storage

Tags: android, file-permissions, chmod

I would like to copy the files (image files captured from the camera app) between internal storage, from /data/data/[my app]/photo to another folder within the internal storage.

As you can see in the screen shot below, I have successfully changed the permission of both directories into '777' via the below code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data/[my app]/photo", null, new File("/data/data/[my app]/photo"));
```

So, I use the similar code to change the permission for the files in the "photo" folder but nothing happens.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data/[my app]/photo/2_20130406_143344");
```

It would be very grateful if someone give me some direction as it has bothered me for the entire weekend.

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: The camera app does not store in /data/data/... You do not have to mess around with linux type permissions just to copy some files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying from one internal location to another and created by your app, you do not need additional permission. Try following

```
ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
File sourceDirectory = wrapper.getDir(SOURCE_FOLDER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File destinationDirectory = wrapper.getDir(DESTINATION_FOLDER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now use a recursive function to copy from source to destination

```
private boolean copyFiles(sourceDirectory, desitnationDirectory);
```

For, how to copy files recursively [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368724/how-to-copy-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders-and-files-into-another-folder).

Camera Images are stored on SD card and, you can always directly access those anytime.

Comment: sorry for late reply as I was sick in the past few days. I tried to create the sourcedirectory using your code above but my camera intent is unable to save the file into the source directory. I need to "chmod 777" before I can save the files. So, I think I need to check my camera intent code before I can further comment on this. But many thanks for your help. (and if it works, I will put that as the accepted answer)